# PHP 5.6.2 + Postgres + Apache 2.4 does not work on Yosemite

Tags: php, postgresql, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I decided to upgrade my mac to Yosemite, but now Postgres is not working.

This is my environment

apachectl -v

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep  9 2014 14:48:20
```

php -v

```
PHP 5.6.2 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2014 15:50:08) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

PostgreSQL 9.3

What I tried to do:

**1. Install with brew**

```
brew tap josegonzalez/php
brew install php56 --with-apache --with-mysql  --with-intl --with-pgsql=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/
brew link --overwrite php56
```

enable the extension

```
sudo nano /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
```

and add

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so

sudo apachectl restart
```

**2. Manual compilation**

```
sudo pecl download pdo_pgsql
sudo tar xzf PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2.tgz
sudo cd PDO_PGSQL-1.0.2
sudo phpize

sudo ./configure --with-pgsql=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/
sudo make
sudo make -j5 test
sudo make -j5 install
```

**3. phpbrew Installation**

```
sudo phpbrew install --mirror http://br1.php.net  5.6.2 +pdo+pgsql=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/bin/
```

It definitely doesn't work when I try with this file:

```php
<?php

  ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
  error_reporting(E_ALL);  
  $host        = "host=127.0.0.1";
  $port        = "port=5432";
  $dbname      = "dbname=peajetron";
  $credentials = "user=peajetron password=peajetron";

  $db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials"  ) or die('Could not connect');;
  if(!$db){
      echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
  } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
  }
?>
```

When I try this code I get the same error:

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/testConnection.php on line 10`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE:**

Acording with the `phpinfo` I've the php.ini in `/etc/php.ini`

Acording with php help I run this command

```
php -c /etc/php.ini
```

And I've the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pdo_pgsql.so' 
- dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226 
 /php_pdo_pgsql.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pgsql.so' 
- dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_pgsql.so,
 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

**Solution**

I uninstalled All and reinstalled all , according with this [post](http://www.iyware.com/osx-yosemite-mamp-homebrew-development-setup/3/)

Comment: Did you check your `php.ini` to make sure the postgres module is loaded? When I upgraded to Yosmite it disabled a bunch of modules.

Comment: yes, of course, I run the command `php --ini` and I get `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini` then I add the extension `extension=pdo_pgsql.so`

Comment: What is `phpinfo()` telling you about your Postgres config?

Comment: The only thing that I find with postgres or pgsql is `PostgreSQL  Jouni Ahto, Zeev Suraski, Yasuo Ohgaki, Chris Kings-Lynne`, php does not load the postgres module

Comment: Double check the `php.ini` path that is reported in your browser when you run `phpinfo()`. Sometimes `cli` and `fpm` have different `php.ini` files.

Comment: intersting, I've in the `phpinfo()`  `/etc/php.ini` and I added the extension to this php.ini but not works, why?

Answer (score 3):

You have two copies of PHP installed. Mac OS X comes with a copy of PHP installed at `/usr/bin/php`. When you use the `homebrew` package manager, it installs packages in `/usr/local/Cellar` and then symlinks them (*when appropriate*) into `/usr/local/bin`. You can verify this by typing `/usr/bin/php -v` and `/usr/local/bin/php -v` and you should get two different outputs.

When you installed `postgres` with `homebrew`, it configured the `homebrew` installed copy of PHP to use `postgres`. If you run `/usr/local/bin/php -r 'phpinfo()'`, you should see that `postgres` is installed.

The copy of `apache` that you have running is configured to use the copy of PHP that is installed by Mac OS X, instead of the copy that `homebrew` installed. You need to reconfigure Apache to use the correct PHP module.

Try editing the `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file with your favorite text editor. Find the line that says:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Change it to:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Save the file, then run `sudo apachectl configtest` and `sudo apachectl restart`. Point your browser back to the `phpinfo()` file and you should see `postgres` configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1) run yum install php-pdo_pgsql

2) add these lines to `php.ini`

```
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pgsql.so
```

3) restart apache

Done

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this problem using:

```
brew install php56 --with-mysql --with-homebrew-apache
```

And then, add to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module  /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```